# Create Eclipse project automatically from existing source code

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking for a way to generate/create an eclipse project automatically, perhaps using the command line (without using the Eclipse wizard).

I have a set of hundreds of Java projects that I need to import to the workspace (*they are not Eclipse projects*, but projects that I need to create from existing source code), and the manual way of creating new Java projects using the wizard takes a significant amount of time.

Comment: you have hundreds of projects? or hundreds of files? if projects, what kind of projects? eclipse?

Comment: I have hundreds of Java projects. They are not eclipse projects. The normal process is creating a new project using the wizard, and changing the location to the project's source directory, and then continuing.

Comment: what is java project? do you mean simple java-files? you can have an eclipse-project, or a netbeans-project...

Comment: Yes, simple java files. Consider it similar to downloading a java project from a github repository. It cannot be imported using the import tool.

Comment: Dou you have Java Projects or Java Classes in packages ?

Comment: Java classes. They are essentially java projects, but not eclipse projects that can be imported easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the projects all in the same folder, you can browse to that directory and select all the projects inside that folder.

Comment: They are not eclipse projects yet. So I cannot use the import function.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using Maven ? On one hand you can create a project with a specific archetype, and on the other hand you can convert it to an Eclipse project.

See http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

Answer (score 0):

As you say you have .java files, and no projects (there are no java project files like you mean), you will have to create the Project yourself.

In your Eclipse, create a new Project, and load the required .java files into it. This should do the work.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to avoid with the question!

Comment: Well, you can try to avoid it, but with no success. You have to build the projects yourself, unfortunately